# MVC Need to mix string and c# code in the razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to show this:

Displaying `Model.AgreementsList.Count < Model.Filter.DisplayLastAgreementsCount ? Model.AgreementsList.Count : Model.Filter.DisplayLastAgreementsCount` of `@Model.AgreementsList.Count`

What i need to write in cshtml file ?
I played with `@` and `{}` and didnt find the solution.
thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use `@()` (using `@{}` only executes the enclosed code and does not write anything to the response stream)

```
@(Model.AgreementsList.Count < Model.Filter.DisplayLastAgreementsCount ? Model.AgreementsList.Count : Model.Filter.DisplayLastAgreementsCount)
```

But rather than doing this kind of thing in the View, you may be better off making a ViewModel or even using `ViewBag` and assigning this output from the Controller.

Comment: Thanks. I added my variable to viewbag and it shows fine. added zero count check too.

Comment: Good to hear it! If an answer on StackOverflow answered your question (like this one ;]), please accept the answer by clicking the tick next to the answer (also you get additional rep for doing this!)

Answer (score 0):

use `@:` for writing a string and `@` for retrieving data from model.